# jQuery Hold Element's Classes in Static Variable and Reuse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

Suppose I have an element with multiple classes: `<div id='foo' class='Test1 Test2 Test3'>foo</div>`

And a script that executes on every keyup event:

```
$('#foo').on('keyup', function() {
     // Do something here that changes the classes
});
```

How could I capture the initial classes of this element before the initial keyup (and only the first initial change), store them in a variable, and reapply them to this element?

I thought about using a global static variable but I believe there's a better solution out there.

Comment: I think you meant `id='foo'` not `id='#foo'`. But to answer your question, couldn't you check for a data attribute on the element and if it exists do nothing, otherwise write the classes to it?

Comment: Oops! Thanks for spotting that typo! Well, I suppose you could check the data attribute on the element but what if my keyup function changes the initial set of classes? The variable holding the initial set would reupdate and I wouldn't be able to ignore further changes caused by each keyup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the element's classes to a data attribute if that attribute is uninitialized.

Otherwise, restore the element's classes from that data attribute:

```
$('#foo').on('keyup', function() {
  if(!$(this).data('classes')) {
    $(this).data('classes', $(this).attr('class'));  //store initial state
  } else {
    $(this).attr('class', $(this).data('classes'));  //restore initial state
  }
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer and very clever thinking! Thank you, Rick :-)